# Проблема с кодировкой | python | requests | ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, requests, кодировка

при парсинге сайта с библиотеками requests и cloudscraper на ubuntu server возникают проблемы с кодировкой

```
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
answ = scraper.post('url', data = payload, headers=head)
al = answ.text
print(answ.encoding)
print(al)
```

при запуске кода на windows всё выводится как надо, а на убунту выводится это:

```
utf-8
*�疶_g�h�W�����i��ud��(и дальше ещё много похожих символов)
```

Comment: Это вообще не похоже на текст в какой-либо кодировке, больше на бинарные данные.

Comment: Предположительно, ваш запрос получает данные не в той кодировке, а ubuntu уже выдает в utf8.